# Get map value with RXJS and angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I just updated angular and this doesn't work anymore. I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. The .get function seems to no longer work. Any ideas?

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'users/login', body, {
        headers: headers
    })
        .map((res:any) => res.headers._headersMap.get('auth'))
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.get()` on the `headers` object directly:

```
res.headers.get('auth')
```

You will get much more help from your IDE (autocomplete) if you correctly indicate the type of `res`

```
import {Response} from '@angular/http';
...

this.http.post(...)
        .map((res:Response) => res.headers.get('auth'))
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked great! Not sure why it worked before. I'll be better about the types in the future.